# is illegal hardware instruction caused by running a file that is too large on your program?

Tags: c

I made a binary search tree in c that works on a file with 1200 words. So i made a file with 27,000 words and got this error.

```
administrator@macbookpro ~ % gcc tree.c                  
administrator@macbookpro ~ % ./a.out  < words.txt
zsh: illegal hardware instruction  ./a.out < words.tx
```

Comment: This is (probably) caused by a bug in your program.  However, we cannot be sure, one way or the other, as you have not posted the source code.  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.  It would also be very helpful if you posted a (very few) line of your input file, so we can be sure of the format of the data in the file.

Answer (score 4):

The size of the input file itself will not cause an illegal hardware instruction fault in your program. Errors in your program can cause that, and those errors can be triggered by various factors, including the size of the input file.

There is a bug in your program.